# Identifying CSS position type of an element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

My element has the following CSS style:

```
#span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

Is there a way to read the `position` type with JavaScript? I've tried these two approaches:

```
document.getElementById("span").getBoundingClientRect()
```

```
document.getElementById(id).style.position
```

Neither fetches the `position`. Is there a better way to go about doing it or an actual way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) with a reference to your element to get the value of styles applied via CSS.

> The `Window.getComputedStyle()` method returns an object containing the values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.

The important part is that all stylesheets are factored in.

```js
const foo = document.getElementById('foo');

console.log(`foo.style.position: ${foo.style.position}`);
console.log(`foo.style.top: ${foo.style.top}`);
console.log(`foo.style.left: ${foo.style.left}`);

console.log(`getComputedStyle(foo).position: ${getComputedStyle(foo).position}`);
console.log(`getComputedStyle(foo).top: ${getComputedStyle(foo).top}`);
console.log(`getComputedStyle(foo).left: ${getComputedStyle(foo).left}`);
```

```css
#foo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">Hello, there!</div>
```

If you're after the actual location on the page instead of the value of the styles applied, you should check out [Retrieve the position (X,Y) of an HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element?rq=1).